# How to pass arguments to the selector in NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter

This code checks when the app becomes active and runs a specific method `dataMain()`. I added a argument to `dataMain(productCode: String)`.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: "dataMain",
            name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil)
```

Is there any way I can pass the `productCode` argument to the selector?

Comment: If `dataMain` is the selector then it doesn't have any arguments. Try `dataMain:` and it will receive the notification as argument.

Comment: How do I pass the argument?
datamain:ProductCode?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't.. Can you post a bit more context of you code? Where are you writing that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the productCode variable at the time of registering for this notification, then you could use a different notification observing method.

```
let productCode = "A string"

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
    object: nil,
    queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (notification) -> Void in
        self.dataMain(productCode)
}
```